# Asus zenbook UX303UB does not resume from suspend (ubuntu 14.04) when charging

Tags: 14.04, suspend, power-management, asus, battery

I've just purchased Asus Zenbook UX303UB which came with Windows10. I replaced the original system with Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS and now I have one issue - the laptop does not resume from suspend when I open the lid & it's charging (on battery everything works fine). However, the suspension works from the menu or with the power button. In system setting I have "suspend" in both AC and DC mode.

I haven't found any solution and as I'm quite new to this system, I will be grateful for any help:)

Update - the same problem is on battery, even "suspend" from the menu does not work.

Update - suspend does not work from the menu and when closing the lid. It works only if I use a shortcut in the taskbar.

Comment: Does it work from the menu or not? Please edit your question to describe the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the very same problem with an Inspiron Dell, the solution was to swotch from the Open graphic card drivers to proprietary ones (you can choose them from "additional drivers" from the Bash)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem but am dual-booting off GRUB. In the end, the solution that worked for me was to boot to Windows 10, open a command prompt, and give it a `powercfg /h off` to disable hibernate mode. Probably also toggleable in the BIOS?